# Running several nodes under a "top" node

Tags: ros, simpleactionclient, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have organized my code in such a way that when I run a *"main"* file, it calls methods in other classes, from other packages, to accomplish a task. I soon realized that the classes written, requires a rospy node so that it can communicate with `ROS_MASTER`.
But I cannot initialize other nodes under the "main" node as i think ROS only allows one node to be initialized and not a node inside another.

Example: The classes in the other packages use SimpleActionClient/action client which uses the actionlib, that requires to initialize a node to publish messages and call services.
I had only initialized a node for the *"main"* method.
And since I cannot initialize any more nodes, the code does not really do anything 
Any advice on how to resolve this issue? or any alternative ideas?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9944/running-several-nodes-under-a-%22top%22-node/) by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2011-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-05-12**:
Sorry about that!, hope this edit makes sense..

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-11**:
Can you update your question to clarify what you're trying to do, and what isn't working?  Possibly provide an example.  From your description everything sounds doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what I understand you want several classes of your program to use ros-node functionality. You can just pass them the node handle in their constructor and store it in a member variable. See [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rgbdslam/html/openni__listener_8cpp_source.html#l00038) for such a constructor definition.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-05-12**:
Thank You!..it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming your using c++.

You can create as many NodeHandles as you want in your code.  You only need to call ros::init at the top of your main. Everything else can just create a ros::NodeHandle using any valid constructor.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-16**:
Yes, that's right, Felix. It took me a while to figure that out, too - I used to pass node handles around everywhere, but that is not necessary.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-14**:
Are you saying, when I create two node handles in the same executable, they both refer to the same node?

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-05-12**:
Actually, Im using Python, according to http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown, it mentions that "You can only have one node in a rospy process, so you can only call rospy.init_node() once" But I got it to work by passing it down to the constructor, like you said.